# Finding child canvases in frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, tkinter-canvas

Lets say I have a frame which has many widgets inside it, including canvases labels and buttons.

Can i use:

```
counter = 0
for Canvas in frame.winfo_children()
    counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
```

to find the the number of canvases in that frame?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work. You have to ask tkinter for the class of the widget:

```
counter = 0
for child in frame.winfo_children()
    widget_class = child.winfo_class()
    if widget_class == "Canvas":
        counter = counter + 1
```